# How to show a selected cells information based on check box data list

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of potential parts (let's call it the 'parts table') for a project, with a tick box column to "pick" the desired part. This is a document in google sheets and everything is in the same document as well as on the same page of the document.
In a secondary table (let's call it the 'chosen part table') I have a list of the definitive parts chosen. How can I link a cell in the 'chosen parts table' to display the part link of the 'parts table' depending on which checkbox is ticked? See my example below and the original document for context.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eB11KTt4xhkQQfuQg-Jfu8mvQ9VpP7PFsbAduetdvYI/edit?usp=sharing

[image: Example of my problem]

Comment: @BlindSpots  Here is a custom google sheet that I made as a working example. I put all the info in the sheet itself because of the limited amount of characters I can use in the comments. Thanks in advance :)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eB11KTt4xhkQQfuQg-Jfu8mvQ9VpP7PFsbAduetdvYI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for and more, thanks a bunch! I think I understand most of what you did, but how did you create the dropdown list? When I try to insert data validation it doesn't seem to work the same way as the drop down list you made. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: Take a look at this example sheet with dependent lists.  Ideally if you can store all your parts list in one table then it is easier to query.  You could have a lot of columns that don't overlap between products as long as each produtc shares the key columns you need to cross reference like price, product name, product group (category), links, etc.  [shared spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18LHZfj3lL9UvQprw_t16ezLbFNPg4nIbLE9weroSA-I/edit#gid=2100307022)  FYI "Data Validation" and "Part Groups" tabs could be combined.